# Will my ASUS P5MT-M motherboard support newer CPUs?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, hardware-rec, requirements

I have an ASUS P5MT-M motherboard with an Intel E7230/ICH7R chipset.
I need to know what newer CPUs it will support.

**Namely:**
Core2 CPUs (Conroe, Kentsfield, Yorkfield, Allendale, and Wolfdale)
Dual-Core Pentium CPU's (Allendale and Wolfdale)

ASUS, Intel, CNet, and Wikipedia all seem to produce vague, conflicting information.
Any advice would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one of the earlier socket 775 server motherboards, it looks like the latest you can get away with is a few of the Dual Core Pentiums - see below.

On another note, I have built a few with similar chipset and did manage to get away with the first generation Core 2 via a third party BIOS upgrade, but I could swear it did not perform as well as it should and I would not recommend anyone to proceed down the same route.

[Click here for the official supported list -](http://usa.asus.com/Product.aspx?P_ID=ajHa5grlVqAtbKo8)

P4-505/505J (2.66 GHz) (533 FSB)(E0,D0)

P4-506 (2.66 GHz) (533 FSB, EM64T)(E0,D0)

P4-506 (2.66 GHz) (533 FSB, EM64T, revG1)

P4-515 (2.93 GHz) (533 FSB)(E0,D0)

P4-516 (2.93 GHz) (533 FSB, EM64T)(D0,E0)

P4-516 (2.93 GHz) (533 FSB, EM64T, revG1)

P4-520/520J (2.8E GHz) (800 FSB) (D0)

P4-521 (2.8GHz, 800 FSB,HT, L2 1MB)(D0,E0)

P4-530/530J (3E GHz) (800 FSB) (D0,E0)

P4-531 (3GHz, 800 FSB, L2 1MB)(D0,E0)

P4-540/540J (3.2E GHz) (800 FSB) (E0,D0)

P4-541 (3.2GHz, 800 FSB, L2 1MB)(E0,D0)

P4-550/550J (3.4E GHz) (800 FSB) (D0.E0)

P4-551 (3.4GHz, 800 FSB, L2 1MB,D0,E0)

P4-560/560J (3.6 GHz) (800 FSB) (DO,E0)

P4-561 (3.6GHz, 800 FSB, L2 1MB)

P4-570J (3.8 GHz) (800 FSB) (D0,E0)

P4-571 (3.8GHz, 800 FSB, L2 1MB V E0)

P4-630 (3.0E GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, EM64T, HT)

P4-631 (65nm,3.0GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, revB1)

P4-631 (65nm,3.0GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, revC1)

P4-631 (65nm,3.0GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, revD0)

P4-640 (3.2E GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, EM64T, HT)

P4-641 (65nm,3.2GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, revB1)

P4-641 (65nm,3.2GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, revC1)

P4-641 (65nm,3.2GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, revD0)

P4-650 (3.4E GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, EM64T, HT)

P4-651 (65nm,3.4GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, revB1)

P4-651 (65nm,3.4GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, revC1)

P4-651 (65nm,3.4GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, revD0)

P4-660 (3.6E GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, EM64T, HT)

P4-661 (65nm,3.6GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, revB1)

P4-661 (65nm,3.6GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, revC1)

P4-661 (65nm,3.6GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, revD0)

P4-662 (3.6 GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, EM64T, HT, revR0)

P4-670 (3.8 GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB,N0)

P4-672 (3.8 GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, revR0)

Pentium D 805 (2.66 GHz, 533 FSB, revB0)

Pentium D 820 (2.8 GHz, 800 FSB, revA0)

Pentium D 820 (2.8 GHz, 800 FSB, revB0)

Pentium D 830 (3.0 GHz, 800 FSB, revA0)

Pentium D 830 (3.0 GHz, 800 FSB, revB0)

Pentium D 840 (3.2 GHz, 800 FSB, revA0)

Pentium D 840 (3.2 GHz, 800 FSB, revB0)

Pentium D 920(2.8GHz, 800 FSB, L2 4MB, revB1)

Pentium D 930(3.0GHz, 800 FSB, L2 4MB, revB1)

Pentium D 930(3.0GHz, 800 FSB, L2 4MB, revC1)

Pentium D 940(3.2GHz, 800 FSB, L2 4MB, revB1)

Pentium D 940(3.2GHz, 800 FSB, L2 4MB, revC1)

Pentium D 950(3.4GHz, 800 FSB, L2 4MB, revB1)

Pentium D 950(3.4GHz, 800 FSB, L2 4MB, revC1)

Pentium D 950(3.4GHz, 800 FSB, L2 4MB, revD0)

Pentium D 960(3.6GHz, 800 FSB, L2 4MB, revC1)

Pentium D 960(3.6GHz, 800 FSB, L2 4MB, revD0)

Pentium Extreme ED-955(3.46GHz, rev A0,B1)

Pentium Extreme ED-965(3.73GHz, rev C1)

Comment: i don't think he's asking for pentium 4 support :)

Comment: This is odd, but when I click the link you provided, I get: "Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor SU9400 : 1.4 GHz & Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor SU7300 : 1.3 GHz ... But when I replace the "%5F" in the URL with an underscore I get: "Intel® 1066 MHz P4 in the 775-land Package" ... Again with the confusing information...

Comment: Something is wrong and I am not sure what... Manually copy and paste http://usa.asus.com/Product.aspx?P_ID=ajHa5grlVqAtbKo8 then click CPU supported - however I copied the whole list above. It does not look like it is compatible with the Core 2 line

Comment: Also when I go to ASUS's CPU support page - http://support.asus.com/cpusupport/cpu_support_right.aspx - my motherboard is not even listed under the Socket775 catagory...

Comment: Ah! I found what you were looking at. Wow, they should make that a bit more visable. I saw the "CPU" section on the spefifications tab and thought that was all they had.

Answer (score 1):

according to the "CPU Support List" **Smithfield** and **Presler** Dual-Core Pentium CPU's are supported.

e.g. the Pentium D 960

Allendale and Wolfdale CPUs are NOT supported by this mainboard.

nothing 'vague' on the **[spec sheet](http://usa.asus.com/Product.aspx?P_ID=ajHa5grlVqAtbKo8&content=specifications)**

Comment: I believe you provided the same link, so see my comment on Wil's answer.

Comment: the link woks fine, you may have to clear your browser cache.